# How to perform system restore (c#)

Tags: c#, operating-system, system-restore

Is there is some way to perform system restore from c# code? Any links\sample?

The program can be run form local or remote, whatever is better.

EDIT:

I have a machine that can be used by many users. I want to write a program that after the user check in the computer will run system restore in order to recover the OS and make sure the next user will have a working stable OS.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by system restore? A restore from a backup? Or the Windows feature? I suspect the answer in any case will be "That's not very easy to do."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sysrestore.aspx) guide talks you through it

Comment: This article only shows how to create system restore points, but not how to effectivelly restore the system